# change layer style color using color picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3

I m trying to create a tool in my map to choose the color i want to apply on a specific layer.
I tried to change color randomly like in this following code :

```
function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;

    }

var ab =new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.0)',
      width: 0.3
    }),
     fill : new ol.style.Fill({
   color: getRandomColor()
  })
  })
});
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
  new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() }),
  ab
  ],
  target: document.getElementById('mapid'),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-1095791.453557, 3422374.879112],
    maxZoom: 19,
    zoom: 5
  })
});
```

i found somthing like :  https://jsfiddle.net/7g7Lh2L2/2/

but i don't know how to replace `'#background'` and `'background-color'` with layer proprieties

Thank you;

Answer (score 0):

You should create a style function to achieve what you are looking for with `fill` property. The style function will be called for each object in the map layer and you can check properties of the feature to determine the `fill` for it or call your `getRandomColor()` function:

```
var styleFunction = function() {
  return function(feature,resolution) {
    var style;
    var objProperty = feature.get('<Layer Property Name>'); //Retrieve feature property value
    style = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 10,
        fill: createFillStyle(feature),  //Would call function for each map layer feature to determine fill color
        stroke: createStrokeStyle(feature,resolution) //Example calls function to create stroke for an individual layer feature
      }),
      text: createTextStyle(feature, resolution) //Example calls function to create text style for individual layer feature
    });
    return [style];
  };
};

var ab =new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: styleFunction()
});

var createFillStyle = function(feature) {
  var fillColor = getRandomColor();
  return new ol.style.Fill({color: fillColor});
}
```

The example above will call `getRandomColor()` for each feature on the map layer (Each feature will have a different color on the map layer).  If only one color for all features on the map layer, call `getRandomColor()` before `var ab =new ol.layer.Vector` to set one random color for all map features on the map.

Do a search for `openlayers style function` for more examples.